# Mysql comando alter table, diferença de "modify" e "change"?

Tags: mysql, sql

*Quais as principais diferenças no change e modify, em quais casos devo usá-los ?*

```
alter table cadastro change nome nome varchar(20);
```

```
alter table cadastro modify nome varchar(30);
```

Comment: Basicamente o `change` serve para renomear uma coluna, alterar o tipo, valor padrão etc. Enquanto o `modify` fica limitado apenas a alterações de tipo, valor padrão etc. Ou seja, faz "tudo" que `change` faz, exceto renomear as coisas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Cláusulas de Redefinição

Esses 2 modificadores podem ser usados no `MySQL`, eles permitem alterar nomes e definições de colunas que já foram criadas, evitando ter que apagar e criar novamente. Apesar de terem muitas semelhanças, cada um tem um propósito específico.

**Change**

Pode ser utilizado para renomear uma coluna e alterar suas definições, como o tipo de dados de uma coluna, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    nome int,
    id int,
    endereco int
);

ALTER TABLE clientes CHANGE COLUMN nome nome_cliente VARCHAR(50);
```

Ele tem mais capacidade do que o `MODIFY`, pois permite a alteração do nome da coluna. Ele é mais utilizado, quando há algum erro no nome da coluna e na suas definições.

Para utilizá-lo, é necessário especificar o nome atual da coluna e depois o nome que deseja renomear, caso não deseje alterar o nome, basta colocar novamente o mesmo nome, para ele permanecer com o nome (que não é o propósito dessa cláusula).

Permite utilizar o `FIRST` e o `AFTER` para reordenar as colunas, por exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE clientes CHANGE COLUMN id id_cliente INT FIRST;

ALTER TABLE clientes CHANGE COLUMN id id_cli INT AFTER endereco;
```

**Modify**

Pode ser utilizado para alterar as definições de uma coluna, mas não o seu nome, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    nome int,
    id int,
    endereco int
);

ALTER TABLE clientes MODIFY COLUMN nome VARCHAR(50);
```

Ele é mais conveniente do que o `CHANGE`, pois permite a alteração das colunas, sem ter para não ter que passar um outro nome para renomeá-la. É mais utilizado, quando quer alterar somente as definições da coluna.

Ele também pode ser utilizado com `FIRST` E `AFTER`, para reordenar as colunas:

```
ALTER TABLE cliente MODIFY COLUMN nome VARCHAR(50) FIRST;

ALTER TABLE cliente MODIFY COLUMN nome VARCHAR(50) AFTER endereco;
```

**Obs:**

> Apesar de funcionar no `MySQL`, o `CHANGE` é uma extensão do `MySQL`
>   para o `SQL` padrão, já o `MODIFY` é uma extensão do `MySQL` para
>   compatibilidade com o `Oracle`.

Você pode saber mais, olhando o seu [Manual de Referência](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).